# access nested json data from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am interfacing with an API which returns JSON data to me. As the results are not stored in a file, but rather server memory, I am having a hard time figuring out how to access the data and write it to my html webpage.  Here's what my $.ajax call looks like:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url:"https://www.xxx/v1/trips/search?  key=xxxx",
            data:JSON.stringify({request : requestTrav1Dest1}),
            dataType:"json",
            success:successFunction,
            headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"}
            });
```

Here's what the JSON I get back from the server looks like:

```
{
"kind": "#tripsSearch",
"trips": {
  "kind": "#tripOptions",
  "tripOption": [
   {
    "saleTotal": "USD294.10",
    "id": "DMfSXrkVQGKTVQsDD5l60N004",
   },
    "saleTotal": "USD333.10",
    "id": "DMfSXrkVQGKTVQsDD5l60N002",
   },
   {
    "saleTotal": "USD225.94",
    "id": "DMfSXrkVQGKTVQsDD5l60N005",
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

What I really need is the saleTotal for each tripOption.

I broke out the function that runs if the query is a success here:

```
function successFunction(servResponse){
        $('#content').load('resultsPage.html #content');
        var newContent = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < servResponse.trips.tripOption[i].length; i++){
            newContent += '<div class="results">';
            newContent += '<p>' + "Option " + (i+1) + '<br>';
            newContent += servResponse.trips.tripOption[0].saleTotal + '<br>';
            newContent += '</div>';
            }

        document.getElementById('content').innerhtml = newContent;
 }
```

Unfortunately, this does not write out anything to the webpage.  So far I can only view the raw JSON results in the Chrome Developer's Toolbar Console.

Can someone please help identify what I need to do differently?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an element on the page with the ID of `content`, it should work fine, you just have a little typo

`document.getElementById('content').innerhtml = newContent;`

capitlize the 'HTML',

`document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = newContent;`

---

`$('#content').load('resultsPage.html #content');` looks incorrect, the 1st parameter should just be a URL. Try commenting it out, for now, since you're changing it's content with the other line.

Comment: Wow, that made a HUGE difference!  For the first time I was able to print to the screen.  Now my only problem is that the saleTotal still doesn't print, it says it's "undefined".  I suspect this has something to do with it being in an array - any suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind - I just figured it out and posted an edit to my code, I needed to add [0] after tripOption ;)

Answer (score 2):

Also, the 4th line should be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < servResponse.trips.tripOption.length; i++){
```

You have:

```
... tripOption[i].length ...
```

The function below should:

- Create one div with the class="results"
- Place several p elements inside this div, each containing a 2-line entry
- Display all this inside the element with an id of "content"

Is this what you want? The CSS that you are currently applying to `.results` may need to be applied to `.results p` instead.

```
function successFunction(servResponse){
  var tripOption = servResponse.trips.tripOption;
  var newContent = '<div class="results">';

  for(var i = 0; i < tripOption.length; i++){
    newContent += '<p>' + "Option " + (i+1) + '<br>';
    newContent += tripOption[i].saleTotal + '<p>';
  }

  newContent += '</div>';
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = newContent;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lexogram/c1wzsqaf/)

Comment: thanks for the tip!  That helped a bunch too, as I mentioned on elzi's comment, I'm still having a problem with the line to print out the saleTotal (maybe because it's in an array) - any suggestions?

Comment: I figured out the problem.  Sorry I can't upvote your answer, I don't have enough reputation points yet, but I really, really, REALLY appreciate the help! :)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was going for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
   var servResponse = {
                "kind": "#tripsSearch",
                "trips": {
                  "kind": "#tripOptions",
                  "tripOption": [
                   {
                    "saleTotal": "USD294.10",
                    "id": "DMfSXrkVQGKTVQsDD5l60N004",
                   },{
                    "saleTotal": "USD333.10",
                    "id": "DMfSXrkVQGKTVQsDD5l60N002",
                   },
                   {
                    "saleTotal": "USD225.94",
                    "id": "DMfSXrkVQGKTVQsDD5l60N005",
                   }
                  ]
                 }
};

function successFunction(servResponse) {
var newContent = '';
 servResponse.trips.tripOption.forEach(function(el,index){                                              
            newContent += '<div class="results">';
            newContent += '<p>' + "Option " + (index+1) + '<br>';
            newContent += el.saleTotal  + '<br>';
            newContent += '</div>';
            console.log(el.saleTotal);
});

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = newContent;
}

successFunction(servResponse);

Using pure javascript forEach loop 

Example Link : http://jsfiddle.net/c1wzsqaf/1/
```

Comment: Thanks for the pure javascript version - always good to know how to do it both ways.